# VS code extension parse value of variable of typescript file

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm working on a VS code extension to parse OpenAPI specs. The spec can be defined as a variable with a fixed name inside a typescript file.

Inside my vs extension I get the document as a string: `const doc = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document;`

How can I parse this string to extract the variable value? I was looking for something like an AST, but maybe there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code does not provide an AST, or similar API, relative to the document you have opened. Which means, if you need something like an AST to parse a document, you will have to do it within your extension.

On the other hand, VS Code provides you the **Go to Symbol** command, which rely on each language extension to expose the symbols within a document. Specifically the `variables` symbol is available for the TypeScript language so, if you need to know the `variables` within a document and its locations, you could use the `vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider` command.